# How to reverse the moving of timeline in blender

Tags: timeline

My timeline is moving in the opposite direction of frames like frame 50 to frame 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely pressing the 'play backwards' button instead of the 'play' button. If not, check your frame beginning and ends. I'm on phone rn so I cant show a screenshot, but its pretty easy to find.

Comment: Thanks it was my mistake, I am using it first time so thank you very much

Comment: If that answer did help to solve your issue, please consider to accept it @VisheshGupta How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour